# Firefox doesn't fire error event on <audio> tag or display fallback text

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, html5-audio

I'm using the `<audio>` tag to play audio files across a number of browsers.

```
var audioTag = document.createElement("audio"),
    sourceTag = document.createElement("source"),
    sorryTag = document.createElement("div");
sorryTag.innerHTML = "This filetype not supported";
audioTag.onerror = function() {
    //some error handling code
}
sourceTag.onerror = function() {

    /some error handling code
}
sourceTag.src = "myfile.mp3";
audioTag.appendChild(sourceTag);
audioTag.appendChild(sorryTag);
//add audioTag to DOM
```

This leads to

```
<audio>
    <source src='myfile.mp3' />
    <div>This filetype not supported</div>
</audio>
```

Firefox can't play MP3 files, and I'm OK with that. Mozilla [also promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Error_handling) that an `error` event will be dispatched if the `<audio>` or `<video>` tag can't play the media. And also it will go through the tags nested inside the media tag one by one (`<source>` or others, the last presumably being an error message) till it finds one it can work with. None of these seem to work for me; the error event is never fired on the elements nor is the error message displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use <audio onerror="whatever">?  Chances are the error event has already fired by the time your script that adds the onerror runs...

Comment: Not possible. I add the `onerror` event listener before I set the `src` attribute of the `source` tag. Updating code to reflect this.

Comment: And the event fires just fine on other browsers for the `video` tag, Just not on FF for the `audio` tag

Comment: Hmm.  That's odd.  Is it possible to post a link to the page showing the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's a work thing and currently under development. I have found a workaround (based on checking the audio element's networkState attribute after a timeout), which I will post below, once I've verified it's working.

Comment: OK.  If you try to extract this into a standalone testcase, does that still show the problem for you?

Comment: @BorisZbarsky I posted my workaround below. The delay was because I've been meaning to extract this into a standalone test case (still haven't gotten around to do it). I will update my answer when I actually do that (will need to host the media files somewhere so JSFiddle won't help; might create a Github repo). For now, the solution in my answer appears to work for me and this IS an issue. Possibly might be one for the FF bug database

Comment: Hmm.  Given that workaround, what does the actual src value you're assigning look like?  Is it actually a file:// url??  It's hard to file a bug in the bug database if I can't reproduce the problem....

Comment: No not a file:// URL. It's hosted on a server and is a relative URL. I promise to try and have a working test case sometime this weekend. Just been lazy... :)

Comment: @BorisZbarsky Added test case, but it appears to work now, both in the test case and in my application. In my defense, we were on FF 14 when I asked the question, but that would just be lazy on my part. Thanks for the follow through :-)

Comment: Ah, good.  Glad to hear it's all working now.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround I found was:

```
var audioTag = document.createElement("audio"),
    sourceTag = document.createElement("source");

//Add error event listeners for browsers other than FF
audioTag.onerror = function() {
    console.log("file can't be played. error from audio tag");
}
sourceTag.onerror = function() {
    console.log("file can't be played. error from source tag");
}
//The only way to tell that file failed to play on FF
//Timeout is because audioTag.networkState === audioTag.NETWORK_NO_SOURCE
//on IE till it starts downloading the file
setTimeout(function() {
    if(audioTag.networkState === audioTag.NETWORK_NO_SOURCE) {
        console.log("this hack is only for <audio> on FF.");
        console.log("Not for <video> and on no other browsers");
    }
}, 3000);
sourceTag.src = "<file_url>";
audioTag.appendChild(sourceTag);
```

Basically, create the media and source tags, add error handlers, then append the source tag to the media tag and if the error event fires, then you know the file is unplayable.

On FF, the error event doesn't fire and you have to rely on the `networkState` flag of the `<audio>` element, comparing it to `NETWORK_NO_SOURCE`. You can't inspect it immediately after setting the `src` attribute of the `<source>` element because on IE `networkState === NETWORK_NO_SOURCE` till the browser actually starts downloading the file. For this reason, set a timeout of about 3 seconds (it's not an exact science) before checking the flag value and there's a good chance that you will have given IE enough time to determine if it's capable of playing the file.

**UPDATE**

Wrote a test case for this: http://jogjayr.github.com/FF-Audio-Test-Case/ but the error event fires OK there. Guess I was wrong; that or it was broken on FF14 (which I was using at the time), because the error event fires OK in my application too. Thanks @BorisZbarsky